# Translate all possible Dialing Codes into written-out Country Names

Tags: php

I have a huge list of mobile phone numbers in my database where i saved the dialing codes like `7` in a separate column. I'm trying to turn the dialing codes into written-out country names programmatically like:

```
foreach ( $customer_bookings as $cdcode ) {

    $customer_dialingcode = $cdcode['dialingcode'];
    
    if ($customer_dialingcode == '1') {
        $customer_country = 'Canada';
    } elseif ($customer_dialingcode == '7') {
        $customer_country = 'Russia';
    }
    
    // and so on

}
```

Any idea how to make this happen for all common / possible dialing codes?

Comment: For one, you're going to need a list of all the country codes. For two, `1` is Canada _and_ the US.

Comment: And instead of a massive if/elseif/else construct, you should rather stick the country names into an array, using the dialing code as key - then you can pick the country out of that directly.

Comment: THX Sammitch & CBroe - ill try it